# Add a new table row to existing table but before the first row

Tags: html, css, node.js, ejs

i am trying to make a transaction details page, how can i make the new input table row on the transactions table sort before the previous one? I use node, mongo, mongoose and javascript and ejs

```
<section id="transactions">

        <div class="mx-5 my-5">

          <table>
            <tr>
              <th>Transaction ID</th>
              <th>Beneficiary Details</th>
              <th>Timestamp</th>
              <th>More</th>
            </tr>



            <% transactions.forEach(function(transaction) { %>
              <tr>
                <td><%= transaction._id %></td>
                <td> <%= transaction.beneficiaryName %> <%= transaction.beneficiaryBank %> <%= transaction.beneficiaryAccountNumber %> <%= transaction.transferAmount %></td>
                <td><%= transaction.time %></td>
                <td><a href="<%= transaction._id %>"></a></td>
              </tr>

            <% }) %>


          </table>


        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are generating the list from transactions, and I guess it's an array of objects, you can use:

```js
transactions.unshift({<newObject>})
```

to add it to the beginning of the array

And if you want to do it with JQuery, use:

```js
$('table > tbody > tr:first').before('<tr><td>Stuff</td></tr>');
```

Comment: I used the first option in my node and it worked perfect.. thank you.